# JS regex isn't matching, even thought it works with a regex tester

Tags: javascript, regex, math, symbolic-math

I'm writing a piece of client-side javascript code that takes a function and finds the derivative of it, however, the regex that's supposed to match with the power rule fails to work in the context of the javascript program, even though it sucessfully matches when it's used with an independent regex tester.

The code is extremely bare-bones at the moment, and I'm planning to [flesh it out](http://www.paulgraham.com/progbot.html/) later.

The browser I'm executing this on is Midori, and the operating system is Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx). Here's the HTML page being used as the interface in addition to the code:

Page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Derivative Calculator
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="derivative.js">
    </script>
    <body>
      <form action="" name=form>
  <input type=text name=f /> with respects to
  <input type=text name=vr size=7 />
  <input type=button value="Derive!" onClick="main(this.form)" /> <br />
  <input type=text name=result value="" />
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

derivative.js:

```
function main(form) {
    form.result.value = derive(form.f.value, form.vr.value);
}

function derive(f, v) {
    var atom = [];
    atom["sin(" + v + ")"] = "cos(" + v + ")";
    atom["cos(" + v + ")"] = "-sin(" + v + ")";
    atom["tan(" + v + ")"] = "sec^(2)(" + v + ")";
    atom["sec(" + v + ")"] = "sec(" + v + ")*tan(" + v + ")";
    atom["1/(cos(" + v + "))"] = "sec(" + v + ")*tan(" + v + ")";
    atom["csc(" + v + ")"] = "-csc(" + v + ")*cot(" + v + ")";
    atom["1/(sin(" + v + "))"] = "-csc(" + v + ")*cot(" + v + ")";
    atom["cot(" + v + ")"] = "-csc^(2)(" + v + ")";
    atom["1/(tan(" + v + "))"] = "-csc^(2)(" + v + ")";
    atom["sin^(-1)(" + v + ")"] = "1/sqrt(1 - " + v + "^(2))";
    atom["arcsin(" + v + ")"] = "1/sqrt(1 - " + v + "^(2))";
    atom["cos^(-1)(" + v + ")"] = "-1/sqrt(1 - " + v + "^(2))";
    atom["arccos(" + v + ")"] = "-1/sqrt(1 - " + v + "^(2))";
    atom["tan^(-1)(" + v + ")"] = "1/(1 + " + v + "^(2))";
    atom["arctan(" + v + ")"] = "1/(1 + " + v + "^(2))";
    atom["sec^(-1)(" + v + ")"] = "1/(|" + v + "|*sqrt(" + v + "^(2) - 1))"; 
    atom["arcsec(" + v + ")"] = "1/(|" + v + "|*sqrt(" + v + "^(2) - 1))"; 
    atom["csc^(-1)(" + v + ")"] = "-1/(|" + v + "|*sqrt(" + v + "^(2) - 1))"; 
    atom["arccsc(" + v + ")"] = "-1/(|" + v + "|*sqrt(" + v + "^(2) - 1))"; 
    atom["cot^(-1)(" + v + ")"] =  "-1/(1 + " + v + "^(2))";
    atom["arccot(" + v + ")"] =  "-1/(1 + " + v + "^(2))";
    atom["ln(" + v + ")"] = "1/(" + v + ")";
    atom["e^(" + v + ")"] = "e^(" + v + ")";
    atom["ln(|" + v + "|)"] = "1/(" + v + ")";
    atom[v] = "1";

    var match = "";
    if (new Boolean(atom[f]) == true) {
        return atom[f];
    } else if (f.match(/^[0-9]+$/)) {
        return "";
    } else if (f.match(/([\S]+)([\s]+)\+([\s]+)([\S]+)/)) {
        match = /([\S]+)([\s]+)\+([\s]+)([\S]+)/.exec(f);
        return derive(match[1], v) + " + " + derive(match[4], v);
    } else if (f.match(new RegExp("^([0-9]+)(" + v + ")$"))) {
        match = new RegExp("^([0-9]+)(" + v + ")$").exec(f);
        return match[1];
    } else if (f.match(new RegExp("^([0-9]+)(" + v + ")\^([0-9]+)$"))) {
        match = new RegExp("^([0-9]+)(" + v + ")\^([0-9]+)$").exec(f);
        return String((match[1] * (match[3]))) + v + "^" +
                   String(match[3] - 1);
    } else {
        return "?";
    }
}
```

In particular, I'm having trouble with this pattern:

```
    } else if (f.match(new RegExp("^([0-9]+)(" + v + ")\^([0-9]+)$"))) {
        match = new RegExp("^([0-9]+)(" + v + ")\^([0-9]+)$").exec(f);
        return String((match[1] * (match[3]))) + v + "^" +
                   String(match[3] - 1);
```

Comment: Please state specifically the string and the pattern you are having trouble with. It looks like you have many, I'm not willing to go through and fix the whole program, but I could easily help you with one string.

Comment: I did specify which pattern I'm having trouble with (the one that's supposed to match the power rule). However, since certain users may not be familiar with what that is or how it's supposed to look like, I have further clarified.

Comment: EDIT: Actually, there was a small mathematical error, so I apologise for any confusion I caused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to double-escape your caret:

```
")\\^([0-9]+)$"
```

Otherwise javascript doesn't interpret the backslash as a backslash, and therefore never escapes the caret for the regex.